# Capacity limit for trade boats?

Tags: banished

Sometimes I can't trade bigger amounts of goods because of a limit.

What kind of limit is this?
Do I have to comply with an overall value?

Or is there something like a capacity (dimension, weight) limit?
*(Are the boats that small as the boat footprint and rower may indicate?)*

Or is there some limitation in the mixture of goods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both above answers are correct, however the major issue here is weight. Weight is an attribute in Banished that determines how much fits in a barn, stockpile, or is able to be carried by a laborer. The storage limit is not on the trade boat, but instead on the storage in your trading post.

```
Firewood                         4
Logs                            11
Stone                           15
Coal                            15
Iron                            25
Most Food, Herbs, Ale            1 
Mushrooms                        4
Tools, Leather, Clothing, Wool  10
```

The table for weights (and the capacity of storage buildings) is here on the wiki: 
http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Weight

Comment: For the purposes of trading, it'd be really nice to see a column with the value per unit, and value per weight.

Answer (score 2):

The only limit is how much you can store in your trading post: your purchase must not violate max capacity of it, as there is no overstuffing mechanic in the game.

*i do not recall whether you must have free space for both: their stuff and yours e.g. you can not trade 20k wheat for 20k peaches; or you just need to make sure your trading post is completely empty to be able to receive 20k peaches*

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm you do not need space for both (ie you can trade 20k wheat for 20k peaches)
You just need space for what your getting.

I had this issue when trading for Coal.

Coal takes up ALOT of space

I was buying 1500 coal but only about 800 or so would fit in the trading post at one time so I had to buy 800 and wait for the Traders to empty a bunch of it before I could trade for the rest.

I had firewood in the trading post at the time to pay for it so I'm not 100% sure of the numbers.